# Cannot install Charts in QT

Tags: windows, qt, qt6

I cannot install charts in QT. I don't know why.
I'm using gnu gpl v3 license.
OS system: Windows 10. Do you know why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MrYui The "Maintenance installer" has some quirks, but please check "Qt > Qt 6.1.2 > Additional libraries" and then "Qt Charts" is the third checkbox item. (since you have checked that version.) Then the 0.0 byte there change to 30 MiBytes.
The checkbox you marked does not change as well for me. Qt Chart is NOT an external plugin anymore.

Comment: I will do that later. I give you a reply! Thank you.

Comment: Is QT Charts not free to use?

Comment: AFAIK it was free to use in later vrsions of Qt5, because LGPL 3.0. For Qt6 I have no dependable knowledge.

Comment: So...what should I do if I want free desktop GUI with charts? I know JavaFX, it would work. But it's not very popular for the job market. Same for GTK+.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, so don't take my answer as "ready for court". Qt states on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html "Licenses

Qt Charts is available under commercial licenses from The Qt Company. In addition, it is available under the GNU General Public License, version 3. See Qt Licensing for further details." So I understand that you can use Charts within your program no matter if you have a commercial or "hobby, but open source" project (with fitting licensing).